# Java class without main method will run?

Tags: java

```
class Demo{

    static {
        System.out.print("Hello");
    }
}
public class A{

    public static void main(String[] argc){
        Demo demo = new Demo();
    }
}
```

Q1. can we compile this java class?
Note we don't have a main method in this class.
Q2. Is there any way we can print the message "Hello" which is there in the class?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I had similar questions about a week ago, of whether or not the class loader would load this class and run the static block. Do you know what I did? Exactly what @VivinPaliath suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1. can we compile this java class? Note we don't have a main method in this class.

Yes, that class should compile. There's no requirement that says you need a `main` method in every class for it to compile. (Most of your classes won't have their own `main` method.)

> Q2. Is there any way we can print the message "Hello" which is there in the class?

Yes, you can load the class in another class that does have a `main` method.  When your class loads the [static initializer block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7) will be executed, and the message will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

This will be printed when the class will be loaded by the classloader.

**More info:**

The class as it is has no sense as it will not run anything. But given the static blocks are called on loading the class by classloader there might still exist another class which references this class - this will happen `demo` will be loaded by classloader and the static block executed.

Comment: This would be a good answer with substantially more information. As is, frankly, I doubt the OP will find it at all useful given their apparent knowledge level.

Answer (score 1):

This will complile since there are no sytax errors. However, the execution of a java program starts with the main method. Since you have no main method, you have no way to run System.out.println method.

Comment: That's only true if you assume `demo` is the only class. If there's another class which references `demo`, the static initializer will run.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we compile this java class?

Yes

> Note we don't have a main method in this class.

Main is the starting point for any programme and required to actually run it

```
Is there any way we can print the message "Hello" which is there in the class?
```

As you used static block,this will be printed when the class loading. So your programme is sufficient for this but will do it class loading

Answer (score 0):

This code will not run on Java 7.  Java 7 checks for the presence of a main method before initialising the class.  It works on Java 6.

BTW Try this on a Windows machine

create a file called A.java

```
class Con {
    static String hi = "\n\nHello World!\n\n";
}
```

and just compile it

```
javac A.java
```

and see what happens !! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Open command prompt and go to the location where the file is present.

```
javac YourClassName.java
```

It will compile the program. Make the function and class as public. You can call it from any other function of another class.